# Form to Javascript without hitting submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, webforms

I was wondering if you guys could help. I've been searching for an answer for a week so far and I can't figure it out. I'm really new to Javascript (although I've used PHP and HTML for a few years). Basically I'm trying to use javascript to calculate an end date from a user entered start date, and a duration, and i'm struggling. I want the date to be updated when ever the user updates either form option:

The code I've got is as follows, but I currently just get the following error:

start: Invalid Date
expire: Invalid Date

I already have a script that checks the date is a real date, so for simplicity i've left that out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setExpDate(){
formDate = document.getElementById('startDate');
number = document.getElementById('days');
// set number of days to add
var interval = number;
var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(formDate));
document.write('start: ' + startDate);
var expDate = startDate;
expDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);
document.write('<br>expire: ' + expDate);
};
</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" id="startDate" name="startDate" onblur="setExpDate()" value="01/01/2015">  

<select name="days" id="days" onblur="setExpDate()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example using [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and splitting the date string for the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to avoid string parsing issues.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myStartDate" value="01/01/2015">
<select id="myDays">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<div id="myResult"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('myStartDate'),
    selectElement = document.getElementById('myDays'),
    resultElement = document.getElementById('myResult');

function updateResultElement() {
    var parts = inputElement.value.split('/'),
        dateObject;

    parts[1] -= 1;
    parts.reverse();
    dateObject = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, parts));
    dateObject.setUTCDate(dateObject.getUTCDate() + Number(selectElement.value));
    resultElement.textContent = dateObject.toUTCString();
}

inputElement.addEventListener('change', updateResultElement, false);
selectElement.addEventListener('change', updateResultElement, false);
updateResultElement();
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kfHRb/)

Comment: Hi! I just wanted to say thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it! Worked a treat

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting the element, but not the date value. so just read the value of input. it should be fine.

```
formDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
number = document.getElementById('days').value;
```

working version: http://jsfiddle.net/9f5q5/